# Use a switch activity to launch one activity or another -> back button

Tags: android

depending on some settings I decide which activity to start. This decision is done in some sort of switch activity whose only task is to start the corresponding activity (it also has no UI which is defined in the android manifest).

This construct works quite well but when I tap the back button, the app doesn't respond anymore, because it tries to open the switch activity but it has no ui. When I give the switch activity back its ui, I can close the app but I always see the empty switch activity, which is sort of ugly ;-)

I also tried to kill the app when back is tapped in one of the switch activity's successors with no success.

Any help would be great.

Bye!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you launch the next activity , call `finish` and remove the Ui less activity

Comment: Ah, sometimes it's that easy and you don't see it ;-) Thanks!